# Citrix XenApp hides task bar

Tags: citrix, xenapp, xendesktop

Our customer complains that their taskbar is hidden once they connect to the application through Citrix.

I tried to found out some solutions online but couldn't get much information apart from checking taskbar configuration.

Could someone help how to get rid out of this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like and issue with seamless flags
https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX101644

Also, check your windows build. Make sure you don't remove the short name (it was a security issue sometime back) for the programs files folders. In CMD, go to the root of C and type DIR /x
Should look like

12/30/2016  05:36 AM              PROGRA~1     Program Files
02/24/2017  05:18 AM              PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)

Comment: So, which seamless flags would you say are causing this issue?
What would the short name affect? What to do when the short name is disabled?